# AS3 cast String as an Object

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to convert following string to an object considering the object in the string exists:

`var exampleStr:String = "myObject.property1.property2";`
`var exampleObj:Object = exampleStr as Object;`

How would I achieve this, and is there an alternative to a method you can provide?

Comment: Did you mean to not include the `""` quotation marks around `myObject.property1.property2`?

Comment: Quotation marks are meant to be there. I'm trying to evaluate if dynamically created object is missing any of chained properties.

Comment: I see what you mean now - you can achieve that using recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple function like this:

```
function getRValue(target:Object, chain:String):*
{
    for each(var i:String in chain.split("."))
    {
        if(target.hasOwnProperty(i)) target = target[i];
        else
        {
            // Couldn't find property.
            throw new Error("Property " + i + " does not exist.");
        }
    }


    return target;
}
```

With a test:

```
var myObject:Object = {
    property1: {
        property2: "Hello world!"
    }
};

trace( getRValue(this, "myObject.property1.property2") ); // Hello world!
trace( getRValue(myObject, "property1.property2") ); // Hello world!
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this Marty! This is a good way to accomplish this as well.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you are trying to dynamically create an object from an assembled string? If so, I think what you are looking for is:

```
var exampleObj:Object = this[ "myObject.property1.property2" ];
```

This presumes that **myObject**'s scope is "**this**", and that **property2** is an Object as well.

Comment: Good example, but for dynamically created object it will throw an error 1069 for property not found in the working class.

Comment: Well, as long as property1 and property2 exists that code would be fine.  The OP's question is more clear after his comments.  I didn't realize the goal was to confirm the existence of the properties.  :)

Answer (score 1):

```
   //Convert the string to  a property array       
    var t:Array = exampleStr.split(".");

    var exampleObj:Object = null;

    if (t.length > 0)
    {

        var objName:String = t[i];

        //get the object in the class
        exampleObj = this[objName];

        for (var i:int = 1; i < t.length; i++)
        {
            var propertyName:String = t[i];

            if (exampleObj.hasOwnProperty(propertyName))
            {
                exampleObj = exampleObj[propertyName];
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Instead of `var propertyName:String = t[0];` it should be `var propertyName:String = t[i];`

Comment: Yes, it should be t[i].